# Is it possible(how) to use different ojdbc drivers on same project using spring data?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, ojdbc

I have these in my application.properties:

```
spring.first.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:first-datasource-url
spring.first.datasource.username=user1
spring.first.datasource.password=pass1
spring.first.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.second.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:second-datasource-url
spring.second.datasource.username=user2
spring.second.datasource.password=pass2
spring.second.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The problem is that one DB is compatible with ojdbc6 and other compatible with ojbc8.
Is there any way that I can make explicit the version or the jar for each DataSource configuration?

This is my Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
 entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory",
 transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager",
)
public class FirstConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.first.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory firstEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "firstJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateFirst(@Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your versions. ojdbc6 only means that it targets Java 6 and ojdbc8 only means it is for Java 8. The Oracle JDBC drivers are pretty good at backwards compatibility, so unless you are running really ancient and no longer supported Oracle versions, you should be able to connect with the most recent Oracle JDBC driver without problems. So please specify which Oracle versions you are trying to use, and the full version of the Oracle JDBC drivers you're trying to use. It would also be helpful to specifically point out which compatibility problem you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

In case of ojdbc6.jar file, the driver class name is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

In case of ojdbc8, the driver class name is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

You can see the difference in both the classes, so I think that you will be able to use both the jar files in the application as long as class names are different.

I assume that in case of ojdbc6.jar, the property name can be

```
spring.first.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

and in case of ojdbc8.jar, it will be

```
spring.second.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: The class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` has been deprecated for ages. Don't use it. See Oracle's JDBC driver manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/Oracle-extensions.html#GUID-E17FE2C3-9384-432C-9040-09EDF98CB8D6

Comment: Thanks Sir for letting us know.

Comment: Both libs have these paths.

Comment: Try to change the class name and see whether it works.

Comment: The drivers have the same class names, so even if you have both on the classpath, only one gets used (if you're lucky, if you're unlucky you might end up with a Frankenstein using some classes from one, and some from the other).